# sugerencias para escribir la siguiente función de matlab en lenguaje ensamblador x86 con ubuntu

Tags: matlab, ensamblador

Me podrían ayudar a tener alguna idea de como se resuelve el siguiente ejercicio:

**El siguiente código en Matlab permite determinar la parte entera de la
raíz cuadrada de un número en forma recursiva. Plantee el código en ensamblador equivalente y determine el valor aproximado de la raíz de 78999999, en 10, 50, 100 y 500 iteraciones. Los resultados deben visualizarse en consola. Luego, determine el valor N, donde se obtiene el valor entero más cercano a la raíz de ese número.**

Adjunto codigo de la funcion en Matlab:

```
N = 10
i_number = 78999999;
i_sqrt = i_number;

for i = 1:N
    i_sqrt = floor(((i_number / i_sqrt) + i_sqrt) / 2);
end
```

Gracias

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Como sugerencia, el código se incluye en las preguntas como texto, pensando en hacer más fácil que otros repliquen tus problemas y en que no todos pueden ver imágenes con código fácilmente

Comment: Estimo @Alfabravo, escribí esto no para que me den la respuesta solo ideas, ya que al ver el ejercicio no se me ocurre como realizarlo.

Comment: A eso me refiero con que ese no es el formato de pregunta adecuado en el sitio. Si haces el recorrido lo verás más claro

Comment: He editado la pregunta, ahora esta mejor? @Alfabravo

Comment: Hola Francisca, podrías editar la pregunta e incluir en ella en que lenguaje ensamblador deseas convertir el código de MatLab, es decir, si el lenguaje assembler es MIPS o x86, ya que, el repertorio de instrucciones no son iguales. De igual modo, respecto al formato, los compañeros se refieren a que incluyas el código de MatLab como texto, es decir, realiza un copia y pega. Saludos

Comment: Hola @LearningDeveloper gracias por la acotación el lenguaje assembler es x86. Saludos

Comment: Hola Francisca, tenía una duda respecto al código de MatLab ya que hace bastantes meses que no lo uso, ¿`floor` permitía redondear un numero en coma flotante al integer más próximo?. Saludos

Comment: Hola Learning Developer si, la funcion floor redondea los decimales al menor entero más cercano.

Comment: Muchas gracias Leraning Developer por tu ayuda, me quedaron las cosas más claras, si llego a tener alguna otra duda, te puedo contactar?

Comment: Por supuesto, para eso estoy. En este [enlace](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110369/discussion-between-learning-developer-and-francisca) tienes una sala en la que me encuentro para realizar preguntas que no sean muy largas y que por ende, no tengan sentido elaborar una pregunta específica para ello. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estoy muy puesto con el ensamblador x86 pero espero poder darte una idea de como iniciar y plantear el problema. Lo primero que debemos hacer es inicializar las variables tal y como indica el código de MatLab. Para ello, creamos una **etiqueta** con el nombre de nuestra variable y le asignamos el **tipo correspondiente**

Las etiquetas se crean de la forma:

```
nombre_variable:
           tipo_dato   valor
```

En este caso el tipo de dato se corresponde con **long** que sirve para declarar etiquetas (variables) de tipo entero y de tamaño **8 bytes**. A continuación, si queremos igualar el valor de una variable a otra debemos usar la instrucción `.zero 4`. Esto se debe a el registro **FLAGS** que son los registros de estado en los microprocesadores **Intel x86** que contiene el estado actual del procesador. Este registro es de **16 bits de ancho (Que es lo mismo que decir dos elevado a 4, dado que todos los registros ya vienen dados en base 2).**

El código presenta una estructura general que se forma:

```
.section .data  /* Segmento de datos */
   /* Aquí se inicializan variables globales inicializadas */

.section .bss
  /* Aquí se definen las variables globales pero sin inicializar */

.section .text /* Segmento de texto */
.globl main   /* Establecimiento de la etiqueta main global */

main:
```

Por tanto, la inicialización de variables correspondientes sería:

```
.section .data    /* Aquí se declaran variables globales */   

    n:
            .long   10
    i_number:
            .long   78999999
    i_sqrt:
            .zero   4   /* Hacemos un push("hueco")en la pila para almacenar la asignación */
```

A continuación es obligatorio disponer de una etiqueta **main**. Se crea de la misma forma que como vimos anteriormente. Esa **etiqueta main** incluirá todas las instrucciones que no son inicialización de variables globales. Por tanto, dado que el código de MatLab incluye un bucle `for` podemos usar el **registro BX para contar los loops (iteraciones)**

```
.section .text              /* Aquí se define el segmento de código (Instrucciones) */
.globl main                /* Establecemos la etiqueta main global*/

main:
    mov %ebx, 1          /* Inicializamos el registro BX a 1 */
    mov %eax, i_sqrt    /* %eax = i_sqrt */
    mov %ecx, i_number /* %ecx = i_number */
```

Después de la etiqueta main podemos incluir una nueva etiqueta llamada por ejemplo `startloop` para almacenar el bucle `for`

```
startloop:      /* Definimos el inicio del bucle */
    cmpsw bx, 0 /* Si la palabra(dato) == 0 realiza un salto a la etiqueta endloop */
    jz endloop  /* Salto a la etiqueta endloop */
    push bx     /* Almacenamos ese valor en CX */

loopy:          /* Definimos el bucle */

endloop:        /* Definimos el fin del bucle */
   jz result    /* Si se cumple el bucle for realiza un salto a la etiqueta result para que realice la operación deseada */
```

Por útlimo realizamos la operación `i_sqrt = floor(((i_number/i_sqrt)+i_sqrt)/2);`

Para ello hacemos uso de las operaciones correspondientes:

**fidiv (División entera)**

**fiadd (Suma)**

```
result:
    fidiv %eax, %ecx, %eax   /* i_sqrt = (i_number / i_sqrt) */
    fiadd %eax, %eax, %eax  /* i_sqrt += i_sqrt */
    fiadiv %eax, %eax, 2   /* i_sqrt = (i_sqrt / 2) */
```